# Proving that a sum is even if and only if the stated conditions hold

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am so frustrated about this question and I have been working on it the whole day before I decided to post this question.

Let $w,x,y,z$ be nonnegative integers. 
$$w+x+y=z$$ 
Prove that $z$ is even iff $w$, $x$ and $y$ are even or exactly one of $w, x, y$ is even.

What I have so far: 
$w, x, y$ can possibly be odds but if there are two odd numbers then the addition will be even.

Also there is a hint saying $x$ is even iff $x^2$ is even.

Thank you so much.

Comment: "either one w x y is even" doesn't make sense. Did you mean "exactly one of the numbers $w,$ $x,$ and $y$ is even"? (Also, check the formatting of your question; it looks like it came out different than you wanted.)

Comment: what is it exactly to be proven? that Z is even iff all others are even or just one is even?

Comment: So z is even iff all wxy is even of eexactly one is even

Comment: I don't see what is so frustrating here, the question is actually quite easy, if you have an even sum you have to have an even number of odd numbers in that sum

Comment: Are you sure that is the right question.  I can't see how that hint could be used in any way that wouldnt be *much* easier without squaring.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start by writing down the definition of an even number and odd number.

Then you want to prove that only when one of w, x or y is even, or when all three are even, is z even. You can substitute in your definitions of even and odd numbers into w, x and y, and then test each combination of even/odd numbers (remember to use different variables for each w, x and y so that they are not the same number).

For example:

An even number x is defined as x = 2s, where s is an integer.
An odd number y is defined as y = 2k + 1, where k is an integer.

Case 1: One even number, two odd numbers

Let w = 2s, x = 2k + 1, y = 2j + 1 (Where s, k and j are integers)

w + x + y = z

2s + 2k + 1 + 2j + 1 = 2(s + k + j + 1) = z

Which is even, because z is divisible by 2.

The other cases should be easy to do if you follow the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it by cases.

There are either zero, one, two or three even numbers and the rest are odd.

Test them all.

1) They are all odd.

Then:

odd + odd + odd =

(odd + odd) + odd =

even[1] + odd = odd[2].

$z$ can not be even if $x,y,w$ are all odd.

2) One is even the rest are odd.

You have

even + odd + odd =

(even + odd) + odd =

odd + odd = even.

So $z$ can be even if exactly one of $x,y,w$ is even.

3) two are even and the third is odd.

Then

even + even + odd =

(even + even) + odd =

even[3] + odd = odd.

So $z$ can not be even if two are even.

4) All three are even.

even + even + even =

(even + even) + even=

even + even = even.

$z$ can be even if all three are even.

That's all possibilities.

.....

[1]  odd + odd = even

Proof.  Let $a = 2n + 1 $ and $b = 2m + 1$ be two odd numbers. Then $a + b = 2n + 2m + 2 = 2(n + m + 1)$

[2] odd + even = odd

Proof:  ... I don't really have to prove these do I?

....